# Linux l2TPv3 support

Tags: linux-kernel, centos6, l2tp

I use CentOS and it does not have support for L2TPv3 which was introduced in 2.6.35.
CentOS is at 2.6.32. How do I selectively patch just the L2TPv3 changes to my kernel?

Also, these are kernel modules. Would I need to run the modified kernel to be able to insmod these KOs?

Answer (score 0):

Back porting features is a very non trivial task, not something that can easily be done casually. Thus, your best option is to look around whether somebody created the necessary patches for your kernel version.

Also, Linux kernel has no strict interface definitions when modules are concerned, thus it is very desirable that kernel and modules are compiled from the same source. Sometimes it is possible to successfully use "mismatched" modules with a given kernel, but rather frequently an attempt to do so results in various problems.

But if you will adventurous, try using `modprobe -f`. This will disable the module version checking and `modprobe` will try to squeeze the module in (even at a cost of crashing the system on spot).

Comment: I was looking to see if someone from the community has already done the patch as you mentioned. In any case, I found the original diffs that support L2TPv3 and I am applying them. It can be found here: http://marc.info/?l=linux-netdev&m=127022509620463&w=1